# storage size of "vector" isn't known

Tags: c++

I'm given 2 errors:
error: storage size of 'vettore' isn't known
error: expected primary-expression before ']' token

I don't know what to try because I suck at programming.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

double funzione(double vettore[]);

int main()
{
    double vettore[];
    funzione(vettore[]);
}
double funzione(double vettore[])
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    double somma = 0, media, risultato;
    int i = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        cin >> vettore[i];
    }
    if (vettore[a] > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            somma = somma + vettore[i];
        }
        media = somma / a;
    }
    else if (vettore[a] < 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            risultato = abs(vettore[i]);
            somma = somma + risultato;
        }

        media = (somma / a) * (-1);
    }
    return media;
}
```

Comment: In C++, arrays need to have a known size at compile-time.

Comment: `double vettore[];` probably wants to be `std::vector<double> vettore;`

Comment: I know, but when I put some type of value inside the array I get another |error: cannot convert 'double' to 'double*' for argument '1' to 'double funzione(double*)'|

Comment: You should format your code before posting. You can use http://format.krzaq.cc/

Comment: I didn't know,thanks for the info

Comment: You many problems in your code. You use `using namespace std;`. You should avoid it. You use c-style headers in c++ code. You should use `cmath`. You include `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` but you don't use it. You should remove it. You are trying to define an array without size. Use a stl container like [std::array](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::vector](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Oh I see, fixed. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: You reading `a` elements and then you check if `vettore[a]` is positive or negative. That's out of bounds. `vettore[a - 1]` is the last element. You use `std::abs` but also you check if the value is positive and negative. That's strange.

Comment: Basically my program should see if the last value of the array is positive or negative and if the last value is negative I should make all the elements negative, so I opted to just make everything positive and then multiply it by -1

Comment: The name of the array is "vettore". No brackets, no index.

Comment: Did our comments help to fix your problem or is there still a problem with your code?

Comment: @delimiter: But some compilers support VLAs.

Comment: You can neither declare an 0-sized array or an array of unknown size at compile-time however some compilers do support VLAs.(Variable Length Array).

Comment: @Raindrop7 Try `-pedantic -Werror`. clang and gcc won't compile. That's usually a default setting for projects.

Answer (score 1):

You have many problems in your code. You use `using namespace std;`. You should avoid it. You use c-style headers in c++ code. You should use `cmath`. You include `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` but you don't use it. You should remove it. You are trying to define an array without size. Use a stl container like [std::array](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You are reading `a` elements and then you check if `vettore[a]` is positive or negative. That's out of bounds. `vettore[a - 1]` is the last element. I fixed all this points in this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

double funzione();

int main()
{
    std::cout << funzione();
}
double funzione()
{
    std::vector<double> vettore;
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;

    double somma = 0, media, risultato;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    double value;
        std::cin >> value;
        vettore.emplace_back(value);
    }
    if (vettore[a - 1] > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            somma = somma + vettore[i];
        }
        media = somma / a;
    }
    else if (vettore[a - 1] < 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            risultato = std::abs(vettore[i]);
            somma = somma + risultato;
        }

        media = (somma / a) * (-1);
    }
    return media;
}
```

Comment: In addition to all these excellent points, it should also be noted that `funzione` is a terrible name for a function. Also, move variables into the lowest scope. `i` doesn't have to be outside the `for` loop. `vettore` (also a terrible name) doesn't have to be outside the function.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: `using namespace` is not but in source files but in headers it is highly not recommended.

Comment: @Raindrop7 I already fixed 3 or more questions here where the only problem was `using namespace std;` in the main file and a new declaration of a function with a name from namespace `std`. For beginners `using namespace std;` often generates errors that they can't solve. Beginners don't know, which function names they can use and which function names already are used in that namespace.

Comment: Only ever use `using namespace` when you know to ignore the rule not to use `using namespace`.